# QUIC traffic generation

Tags: networking, youtube, iperf, quic

I wanted to know if anyone in this community know/found a way to simulate QUIC traffic profile. For analyzing/simulating youtube over  WLAN (WiFi),  i wanted to know if there is a convenient package like iperf out there.

Thanks
Bharat C P

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there are not any simulation frameworks that can be used to test QUIC traffic.

However there is a remarkable effort in order to provide stand alone implementations with the aim of testing and analyzing QUIC.

I cite just some references you might want to use to this purpose:

- [Official Google Guide](https://www.chromium.org/quic/playing-with-quic) which contains a sample server and client implementation in Chromium.
- [libquic](https://github.com/devsisters/libquic) a library extracted from Chromium's QUIC Implementation
- [quic-go](https://github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go) is an implementation of the QUIC protocol in Go.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to generate QUIC traffic using [`aioquic`](https://github.com/aiortc/aioquic). I'm using KDE Neon, which is an Ubuntu derivative.

```
git clone https://github.com/aiortc/aioquic.git
sudo apt install libssl-dev python3-dev
virtualenv venv1
source venv1/bin/activate
cd aioquic/
pip install -e .
pip install asgiref dnslib httpbin starlette "werkzeug<2.1" wsproto
```

Then, in one terminal, run the server:

```
python examples/http3_server.py --certificate tests/ssl_cert.pem --private-key tests/ssl_key.pem
```

And in another, make an http3 request with the client:

```
python examples/http3_client.py --ca-certs tests/pycacert.pem https://localhost:4433/
```

Done.

You can see the traffic in Wireshark. The version that worked for me was `3.6.5`. Note that you would need to sniff the loopback interface (`Loopback: lo`).

Here's how to install Wireshark `3.6.5`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireshark-dev/stable
```

(need to press enter)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wireshark
```