# Capture/generate QUIC traffic

Tags: wireshark, pcap, quic

I am trying to capture QUIC traffic but not able to. I tried to build chromium from source as
mentioned in the google wiki https://www.chromium.org/quic/playing-with-quic, but this is
cumbersome, I am running into all sorts of build issues.

Also, I tried the approach suggested  [here](https://www.cellstream.com/reference-reading/tipsandtricks/382-using-wireshark-to-analyze-quic-traffic)     to capture
QUIC packets using wireshark , this wasn't helpful.

I also tried "chrome://net-internals" and managed to get a JSON and then I tried converting the JSON to pcap using info from https://www.h21lab.com/tools/json-to-pcap but the script reports error

```
json2pcap.py -p ./chrome-net-export-log.json 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/json2pcap.py", line 527, in <module>
        py_generator(packet['_source']['layers'], r)
    TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I downloaded the source for this script from https://github.com/H21lab/json2pcap.

I'd prefer capturing over generating those packets.
Other details -
Platform - macOS catalina
Wireshark - 3.2.2
Chrome Browser

Thankyou

Comment: You may need to "decode as" quic in wireshark. [This question](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/12750/cant-no-longer-find-quicgquic-protocol-on-wireshark-analysis/) on the Wireshark forums is also relevant.

Comment: Capturing and decoding IETF QUIC with recent builds of Wireshark works flawlessly, see https://github.com/quicwg/base-drafts/wiki/Tools for details. The problem might be that chromium does not speak IETF QUIC yet (but a variant derived from Google QUIC).

Comment: The json2pcap script accepts only jsons generated from tshark. See json2pcap -h

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to use Wireshark version `3.6.5` or better. I was using Wireshark `3.2.3`, and it wasn't showing me QUIC packets. Upgrading showed me QUIC packets when I opened [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) in chrome.

Also, you can generate QUIC packets using [`aioquic`](https://github.com/aiortc/aioquic), and detect the packets in Wireshark. Make sure that you pick the loopback interface in Wireshark when you start capturing.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555261/quic-traffic-generation/73852617#73852617) answer for more details and steps.