# QUIC request with google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, quic

I am trying to force Google Chrome to use QUIC as the underlying protocol instead of TCP.

I used this command to force QUIC through the command line, but it doesn't work:

```
chrome --disable-setuid-sandbox --enable-quic --origin-to-force-quic-on=IP:443 http://IP:443/
```

Wireshark shows me that Google Chrome is still using TCP for that destination.

BTW i am using google chrome Version 97.0.4692.71

Can anyone help me in that matter.

Comment: You might want to use Wireshark version `3.6.5` or better. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555261/quic-traffic-generation/73852617#73852617) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

just trying to find a solution for chrome to use http3 without forcing it to, does not work for my local nginx-quic setup, firefox works out of the box... Just found your question. If i remember correctly you can only pass a single domain with that flag to chrome. This works for me:

```
--origin-to-force-quic-on=mylocaldomain.local:443
```

Comment: The same for me, I can only make Chrome work with my local HTTP/3 server by forcing origin, and Firefox just works...

Comment: Just found this: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/09/http3-practical-deployment-options-part3/

Are you trying locally, too?
If the certificate is the reason, that would be great, because in dev environment i really do not need it.
And if... Why isnt Chrome showing anything in the console?

Comment: Link with Hashtag to find the topic on that big site quicker: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/09/http3-practical-deployment-options-part3/#additional-issues