# quic-go http3 can not access

Tags: go, ssl, quic, quic-go

My code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/quic-go/quic-go/http3"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello, HTTP/3!"))
    })
    log.Fatal(http3.ListenAndServeQUIC("0.0.0.0:8443", "/usr/local/pki/cert.pem", "/usr/local/pki/cert-key.pem", mux))
}
```

successfully started(no firewall)

[image]

Chrome has enabled quic.

Can't access from browser.(This site can’t be reached)

Comment: Answer: https://github.com/quic-go/quic-go/issues/3890

Comment: Firefox works fine. But chrome still can't use h3 (quic is turned on).

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70826869/quic-request-with-google-chrome , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71252714/why-cant-i-access-google-with-http3-quic